# Ubuntu 23.10 Installation errors involving Nouveau & config failed hub doesn't have any ports!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, usb-installation, nouveau, msi

Current install errors for Ubuntu: Ubuntu 23.10.

Note: I have tried 3 diff type c attached to the MB and 1 to the case; all of them get to the "try to install Ubuntu" window and then, errors ensue, thereafter.

```
1.522496] hub 12-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports!
4.169154] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (192000a1)
13.687128] snd_hda_intel 0000:15:00.6: no codecs found!
```

I can attempt to install, errors related to these come up and then it goes to a screen showing Ubuntu graphic alongside MSI graphic and a loading wheel before the screen goes black, with a cursor.

I'm quite new to this. My graphics card is a MSI Suprim Liquid X 4090 and MB is a MSI MEG X670E ACE - HELP!

Comment: What is your CPU? There have been reports of that error occurring with newer Ryzen 7000 CPUs when trying to run an older kernel that doesn't have support for them yet.

Comment: It's a 7800X3D. Currently, I'm leaning towards a bad SSD (MSI M570 Spatium) , actually. I have a few other ideas but I've had a history of receiving bad parts. Those errors seems more associated with either USB or SSD or MB connection to those but I have lots of good signs of life for MB and OS installs on USB in seeing SSD in BIOS and USB displaying the installed OS installs and launching them. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well I ran into the same problem and the solution was to use the legacy installer of 23.10 which solved that the installer got stuck with these error messages even if they are still displayed. https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/mantic/release/ubuntu-23.10-desktop-legacy-amd64.iso Edit: Which does not solve the problem of running it, which troubles me the same as it hangs on loader.